# Performance overhead of HTML attributes

Tags: html

I have a relatively huge data grid, containing let's say 100 columns and 100 rows. Hence there are 10.000 data cells, aka `td` elements in the `table`.

Let's say for application logic reasons I'd like to add `data-*` attributes to these cells, like `data-fieldname`, etc.

I was thinking about the overall performance impact of having 10.000 attributes defined on 10.000 `td` elements. Can anyone point out the exact behavior of the major browsers when it comes to this scenario?

To be more concrete, I'm asking if defining `data-*` attributes affect DOM loading or rendering time, and on the other hand, how are these attributes stored, how big is the used memory impact.

My question is rather theoretical than practical, so please don't comment or answer about different alternatives.

Comment: The practical answer is always to **benchmark it**. In all important browsers you want to support. Likely you'll find little practical difference. Even if you do, you need to decide whether it's *fast enough* or needs optimisation in exchange for code complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was just curious if there are some basic rules or facts to be aware of.

Comment: If they don't affect how the page gets rendered, then they won't slow the page down. The'll take up a small amount of memory, but it will be under a few KB. It's good to see a hungarian around here BTW :).

Comment: Surely having such a large table will not be very performant anyway so adding attributes won't make much difference

Comment: @Pete yes that's a quite good point :)

Comment: 10,000 is an awful lot of cells. A single English alphabet letter will increase your page's size by one byte. Having 10,000 cells containing nothing more than `data-a=b` will increase your page's file size by 80kb (which is almost the same size as jQuery when compressed). `data-fieldname=b` on every single cell would increase the file size by 160kb. Obviously, the larger the file size, the longer it will take to download.

Comment: Not sure what the question is asking

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I forgot to mention that the related DOM is generated dynamically so it actually won't increase the response size. Although in general it's a good point.

Comment: @Bálint thanks for the comment, it does make sense. If you put together an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the properties don't change how the page gets rendered, then you will either don't have any or just a very slight performance difference. You will use a bit more memory though. Not so much that it would cause problems, but if you need to download it with a very slow internet speed, then you may have a bit öf speed decrease. (If you use chrome, you should test the page with net speed throttling. I'm not sure about firefox)

If you create every element manually, then adding a bonus property would only add a small difference, as you already need to create every element and put ither attributes on them.